# Google Sheets/Excel Formula Countifs Distinct Lead IDs by Name

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a dataset which has various names which had tied associated Lead IDs. In this dataset there are records the name will be matched with the same Lead ID multiple times for example:

[image: Dataset Example]

Does anyone have suggestions how a single excel formula could return results such as this for Google Sheets/Excel?

[image: Dataset Result Expectation]

Comment: You mention COUNTIFS, can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 3):

*Within **sheets** you may try:*

```js
=map(unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),lambda(Σ,{Σ,countuniqueifs(B:B,A:A,Σ)}))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not using [LAMBDA Helper functions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-lambda-helper-functions-lambdas-as-arguments-and-more/ba-p/2576648) and using `COUNTIFS`:

```
=LET(A,A2:A10, B,B2:B10, uxA,UNIQUE(A), uxB,UNIQUE(B),
 VSTACK({"Name","Total Distinct Lead ID"}, 
  HSTACK(uxA,MMULT(N(COUNTIFS(A,uxA,B,TOROW(uxB))>0),SEQUENCE(ROWS(uxB),,,0)))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

`COUNTIFS` counts per unique values (`uxA`) of name `A` the unique values (`uxB`) of name `B`, i.e. on cell `i`,`j` returns the total counts for Lead ID of `uxB` at column `j` for `uxA` at row `i`. Here the output of `COUNTIFS` for the input data:

```
2   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   2   2   1
```

Since we are interested only in distinct values, we use `N()` function to replace the count values with `1` where it is greater than `0`, otherwise return `0`. In order to have the total distinct count we use `MMULT` to sum the total number of ones on each row. `SEQUENCE` builds the row array of `1`'s to do the multiplication. Finally, we use `VSTACK` to generate the header and `HSTACK` to put the output in the desired format.

If you prefer to use a Lambda Helper function instead of `MMULT`, you can try the following:

```
=LET(A,A2:A10, B,B2:B10, uxA,UNIQUE(A), uxB,UNIQUE(B),
 VSTACK({"Name","Total Distinct Lead ID"},
  HSTACK(uxA,BYROW(COUNTIFS(A,uxA,B,TOROW(uxB)),LAMBDA(x,SUM(N(x>0)))))))
```

or just the following taking a different approach:

```
=LET(A,A2:A10, B,B2:B10, uxA,UNIQUE(A),
 VSTACK({"Name","Total Distinct Lead ID"},
   HSTACK(uxA,BYROW(uxA,LAMBDA(x,ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(B,A=x))))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using any <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> helper functions:

**In Excel:**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=LET(
     a,UNIQUE(A1:B9),
     b,INDEX(a,,1),
     c,INDEX(a,,2),
     d,UNIQUE(b),
     HSTACK(d,MMULT(N(d=TOROW(b)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(c),,,0))))
```

---

**In Google Sheets:**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=LET(
     a,UNIQUE(A1:B9),
     b,INDEX(a,,1),
     c,INDEX(a,,2),
     d,UNIQUE(b),
     HSTACK(d,MMULT(ARRAYFORMULA(N(d=TOROW(b))),
     SEQUENCE(ROWS(c),1,1,0))))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A1:A9),BYROW(UNIQUE(A1:A9),LAMBDA(x,SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX(UNIQUE(A1:B9),,1)=x)))))
```

Result:

[image]